# Installing Mercurial: start with Ubuntu Desktop or Server?

Tags: server, system-installation, apache2

I need to set up a Mercurial server for experimentation.  The setup will be in a virtual machine, and I figured this was a good time to check out Ubuntu (the other option was Windows).

The Mercurial server will be light use; as it is purely for lab / demonstration purposes; however, I need to set up a full multi-repository server, which requires a web server (Apache seems to be the obvious choice).

So, the question is: should I start with Ubuntu Desktop or Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need a server? Mercurial is distributed and this is a huge advantage of it.

Comment: @vh1 - that's the great thing about Mecurial (and other Distributed SCM tools) You can use them in a both Centralized and Distributed fashion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't really matter - you can install the same packages (such as `apache2`) on Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop.

If you start with Ubuntu Desktop, you will need to install server related packages whereas Ubuntu Server comes with them pre-installed. You will also probably want to uninstall software not required for a server.

If you start with Ubuntu Server and need/want a graphical user interface (by default it is just command line) and desktop applications, you will have to install these.

[Ubuntu Server FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq)